# If a creature is attacking my character and another shoots from behind, does my character get half cover?

Tags: dnd-5e, cover

I was fighting against 3 human (A,B,C). The first one (A) was attacking just in front of me, the second (B) was 10 feet at the left side but was engaged with my partner, and the third (C) was 15 feet directly behind the first one. C tried to shot at me with an arrow but A was (as I supposed) creating a half cover for me. 
Does it work like that or not?

Comment: Related on [Is there a penalty for attacking through an ally's position while in melee?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/110937/is-there-a-penalty-for-attacking-through-an-allys-position-while-in-melee)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Yes, you have cover

Per PHB 196, the rules of cover state:

> A target with half cover has a +2 bonus to AC and Dexterity saving throws. A target has half cover if an obstacle blocks at least half of its body. The obstacle might be a low wall, a large piece of furniture, a narrow tree trunk, **or a creature, whether that creature is an enemy or a friend**.

The covering creature in your situation is medium, so the exact degree of cover depends on the size of your character but, RAW, your character has at least half cover.

Comment: And what if I grapple the creature? Does that count as three-quarters or full cover or still half cover?

Comment: @prmf89 See [this question on using an enemy as a shield.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/97320/can-i-use-an-enemy-as-a-shield-thus-gaining-benefits-from-cover) If that doesn't answer it for you, then defintely submit a new question!